# locus sections and circles--symmetry

Tags: analytic-geometry, solid-geometry, locus

A. Let L = {(x,y,z)|the distance from (x,y,z) to the y-axis is 6}. Describe what shape L is.

So far, I have that it's a circle, but I'm not sure how to describe it fully. Would it be a circle that has a radius of 6?

Let L = {(x,y)|the distance from (x,y) to the y-axis is 6}.Describe the shape of L.

I was just wondering, why are the answers to this problem and the one before it different?

B. Let L = {(x,y,z)|(x,y,z) is equidistant from (0,0,4) and the plane z=0}. Describe the shape of L using symmetry and logic.

I understand doing this by algebra, but how would the shape be explained using symmetry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For part A:**

The first shape is a circular cylinder of radius 6 whose axis (centerline) is the $y$ axis.

The second one is a circle of radius 6, lying in the $xy$-plane, with center at the origin.

The circle is the intersection of the cylinder and the $xy$-plane (i.e. the plane $z=0$).

**For part B:**

Think about what's happening in the $xz$ plane. The shape is the set of points that are equidistant from the point $(0,0,4)$ and the line $z=0$. You are supposed to know (I guess) that this is a parabola. By symmetry, the 3D shape is a paraboloid (which you get by rotating the parabola around the $x$ axis).

Comment: Thank you! but how would you explain the last part using symmetry and logic? How did you get to that answer? Thanks very much.

Comment: The distance expression in both cases is $\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}$. Since this expression is symmetric in $x$ and $z$, the geometric shape has to be symmetric in the $xz$ directions. Since  $y$ does not appear, the shape must be a (generalized) cylinder that is "extruded" in the $y$-direction. This is because if $(x,y1,z)$ satisfies the equation, then so does $(x,y2,z)$, for any value of $y2$). The only shape that satisfies these conditions is a circular cylinder.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I understand the problem much better now.